# Android TextureView.getBitmap() is very slow

Tags: android

I have an Android app with the camera configured to send its preview to a TextureView. In the onSurfaceTextureUpdated method of my SurfaceTextureListener I pull out the preview frame as a bitmap using:

```
textureView.getBitmap(existingBitmap);
```

It works fine, but takes a very long time (about 200-250 ms for a 720x1280 image). It seems like this should go much faster. Any thoughts on how I can improve the performance of this operation?

Comment: Did you find a solution to this? I am in the exact situation as you.

Comment: Not yet. You probably have to setup an opengl context and read it from a texture, but I haven't investigated that yet. Let me know if you can figure something out.

Comment: @ajselvig Were you able to read it from the opengl texture. i couldn't find a way to do so.

Comment: No, I haven't really looked into it yet (got a bit sidetracked). I think I've been subconsciously not wanting to work on it because I'm frustrated that this is even a problem in the first place.

Comment: Stuck at same problem.
A normal camera preview picture takes 200ms to read on HTC one.

That should be filed as bug to Android, the time is not acceptable

Comment: Did you get any further? Other sources suggest to query the GL context directly.

Answer (score -1):

Using this command to get the preview generates a new bitmap from the preview, this is what is taking the application so long. My suggestion would be to perform this operation in a background thread explained in this link:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

It will also allow you to stack operations that require this operation to be completed first in the onPostExecute function.

This will allow the main UI thread to function and be responsive to anything else the user may need to do during this time.

This may not be the perfect answer you are loking for but hope it helps.